# 3 Different hover effects for 3 different items on 1 hover

Tags: html, css

I have this rather odd request, and its got me a little baffled.

Essentially I have something like this:

01
A Title

1. a item
2. another item

So when the number or the Title gets hovered on. 01 become's white A title becomes red and the list items become white.

Now I know you can do something like

```
.number:hover .title{
}
```

But not to sure how to go about this.

```
<div class="row we-below">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p class="below-num">01</p>
                    <h4 class="below-title">CONTENT</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Research</li>
                        <li>Strategy</li>
                        <li>Copywriting</li>
                        <li>Custom content</li>
                        <li>Content planning</li>
                        <li>Campaign framework</li>
                        <li>Consulting</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p class="below-num">02</p>
                    <h4 class="below-title">DESIGN</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Art Direction</li>
                        <li>Digital Assets</li>
                        <li>Animation</li>
                        <li>Photography</li>
                        <li>Videography</li>
                        <li>Graphic Design</li>
                        <li>Packaging proposals</li>
                        <li>Studio Recording</li>
                        <li>Illustration</li>
                        <li>Branding</li>
                        <li>Iconography</li>
                        <li>Website Design</li>
                        <li>Social Media</li>
                        <li>Activations</li>
                        <li>Campaign Strategy</li>
                        <li>UI Design</li>
                        <li>UX Design</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p class="below-num">03</p>
                    <h4 class="below-title">BUILD</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>App Creation</li>
                        <li>Packaging</li>
                        <li>Prototyping</li>
                        <li>Digital Production</li>
                        <li>Graphic Assets</li>
                        <li>Layout & Design</li>
                        <li>Google Adwords</li>
                        <li>Style Guides</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p class="below-num">04</p>
                    <h4 class="below-title">EXECUTION</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Media buying</li>
                        <li>Media planning</li>
                        <li>Scheduling</li>
                        <li>Community management</li>
                        <li>Website Maintenance</li>
                        <li>Public Relations</li>
                        <li>Project Management</li>
                        <li>Corporate Identity Document</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The Desired effect for the on hover

[image: Desired effect]

Any Advice or tips would be appreciated. I'd like to learn how to achieve this properly thus the qeustion

Comment: can you change the markup or is it untouchable?

Comment: pretty much. a thing of they gave a picture they want the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sibling css selector

```
.below-num:hover {
    color: white;
}

.below-num:hover + .below-title {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly used a mix of both answers thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
.below-num:hover ~ .below-title {
  color: red;
}

.below-num:hover ~ ul li {
  color: white;
}
```

```css
* {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

li {
  color: gray;
}

.below-num:hover ~ .below-title {
  color: red;
}

.below-num:hover ~ ul li {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row we-below">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p class="below-num">01</p>
    <h4 class="below-title">CONTENT</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Research</li>
      <li>Strategy</li>
      <li>Copywriting</li>
      <li>Custom content</li>
      <li>Content planning</li>
      <li>Campaign framework</li>
      <li>Consulting</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p class="below-num">02</p>
    <h4 class="below-title">DESIGN</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Art Direction</li>
      <li>Digital Assets</li>
      <li>Animation</li>
      <li>Photography</li>
      <li>Videography</li>
      <li>Graphic Design</li>
      <li>Packaging proposals</li>
      <li>Studio Recording</li>
      <li>Illustration</li>
      <li>Branding</li>
      <li>Iconography</li>
      <li>Website Design</li>
      <li>Social Media</li>
      <li>Activations</li>
      <li>Campaign Strategy</li>
      <li>UI Design</li>
      <li>UX Design</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p class="below-num">03</p>
    <h4 class="below-title">BUILD</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>App Creation</li>
      <li>Packaging</li>
      <li>Prototyping</li>
      <li>Digital Production</li>
      <li>Graphic Assets</li>
      <li>Layout & Design</li>
      <li>Google Adwords</li>
      <li>Style Guides</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p class="below-num">04</p>
    <h4 class="below-title">EXECUTION</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Media buying</li>
      <li>Media planning</li>
      <li>Scheduling</li>
      <li>Community management</li>
      <li>Website Maintenance</li>
      <li>Public Relations</li>
      <li>Project Management</li>
      <li>Corporate Identity Document</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pretty neat and adding a effect to below-num I would just use ```below-num:hover{ color:white} ``` right

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i can help:
You will need this in your css:

The first is just what it always will be.

```
.number .title{
some style
}
```

The second is is for if you hover on it.

```
.number:hover .title{
}
```

If this isn't what you want please clarify i litle bit better.